# How do I stop Civicrm front end pages throwing a fatal error?

Tags: civievent, joomla, error-page

On upgrading joomla to 3.8, access to civicrm front end pages  (eg event listing)results in no response ie white screen.

Currently running Civcrm 5.6.1. The error does not occur if I log in to the front end as su.

On updating to joomla 3.9 it throws a red fatal error:
0 -   @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/civicrm.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/css/crm-i.css); @import url(/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css);    Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred. You do not have permission to access this page.

Comment: I'm not too famiiar wit Joomla - but is there an equivalent of a templates_c file that you can trash?

Comment: Yes, there is. There are php files, and php.meta files in it, all generated yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

I tried many things, including restoring files from two months ago, and then updating, joomla and civicrm, and then reconnecting to the current database, and also rebuilding from vanilla copies of joomla and civicrm. But this did not solve the problem. The problem disappeared after I edited and saved the 'registered users' access rights in a minor way. The problem was still resolved after I set the access rights back to how they were. What a relief. Tony, many thanks for your reply.